# Nuget not removing updated packages

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I updated several packages in my solution, and for some, after updating it gave put a green checkmark and removed the package from the list.

For others, it did the work to update, but it did not put the green checkmark and did not remove them from the list.  When I tried to update them, I see the image below, with everything disabled.  What's causing this?

[image]

Here is the packages.config for the project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Angular.UI.Bootstrap" version="0.7.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="angularjs" version="1.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Antlr" version="3.5.0.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="bootstrap" version="3.0.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="CavemanTools" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="CommonServiceLocator" version="1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="dotless" version="1.3.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="elmah" version="1.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="elmah.corelibrary" version="1.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="elmah.mysql" version="1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="FluentValidation" version="5.0.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="FluentValidation.MVC5" version="5.0.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="FontAwesome" version="4.0.3.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Glimpse" version="1.8.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Glimpse.AspNet" version="1.6.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Glimpse.Mvc5" version="1.5.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="2.0.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Less.js" version="1.4.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Moment.js" version="2.4.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="MySql.Data" version="6.7.4" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="5.0.8" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="NLog" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="RazorEngine" version="3.4.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="ServiceStack.Common" version="4.0.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="ServiceStack.Interfaces" version="4.0.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="ServiceStack.Text" version="4.0.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="SqlFu" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="structuremap" version="2.6.4.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="StructureMap.MVC4" version="2.6.4.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Twitter.Bootstrap" version="3.0.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Twitter.Bootstrap.Less" version="3.0.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WebActivator" version="1.5.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.5.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WinLess.lessc" version="1.0.14" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

There are several packages that are exhibiting this behavior, jQuery is one.

Comment: Maybe there are some other packages depending on that one. Check your packages.config in that project.

Comment: I clicked on the update all packages and it didn't change anything.

Comment: Can you post the packages.config in that project? Also the one you are trying to update.

Comment: I missed the part you said that the packages were updated, my mistake. It seems like GUI is not updated somehow. Restart Visual Studio and check if they are still eligible for update.

Comment: I've restarted VS several times and rebooted a couple of times as well since I noticed the issue.  I also cleared the nuget package cache as well.

Comment: It may be a bug in NuGet Visual Studio extension.

Comment: I have the same problem.  The list of packages that actually are updated but that don't disappear from this list continues to grow. the individual projects that use the packages don't show that an update is required.